# Pie Chart Label

Tags: javascript, jquery

my pie chart displays perfectly but my labels are placed where they are but not good positioned because they lap on the chart halfway this is my code

```js
function getStatPie(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Dashboard/GetDashboardStatPie",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data.result);
            var statResult = data.result;
            if (statResult != null) {
                if (statResult.totalPaymentChartStat != null) {
                    getPieChart(statResult.totalPaymentChartStat);
                }
                $('.loader-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            $('.loader-wrapper').addClass('hidden');
            abp.notify.error("An error occurred while retrieving Dashboard Pie Chart stats. Contact support", "Error");
            abp.ui.clearBusy();
        }
    });
}
function getPieChart(rawData) {
    $.plot($("#Pie_Chart"), rawData, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                resize: true,
                radius: 1,
                series: [{
                    argumentField: "Branch",
                    valueField: "Number",
                    label: {                     
                        visible: true,
                        customizeText: function (arg) {
                            return arg.argumentText + " (" + arg.percentText + ")";
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
    });
}
```

```html
     <!-- Pie Chart -->
                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                        <div id="Pie_Chart" style="width:400px;height:260px; "></div>

                    </div>
```

this is the image of my pie chart and how it looks with data populated into it, I want the label to not be on the pie and be clear someone help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change `radius: 1,` to `radius: 4/5,`
and if the size is still not you keep changing the radius